# Proving an isomporphism between all real 2x2 matrix under addition and $R \oplus R \oplus R \oplus R$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Here is my current issue: Let $M$ be the group of all real 2x2 matrices under addition. Let $N=R \oplus R \oplus R \oplus R$ be a group under vector addition. Prove the $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic.

I've got the map, but I don't know where to go from here. I feel as if there isn't more than one or two steps, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.  Here is what I have so far:  Map $
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ to $(a,b,c,d)$

Is it as simple as stating that $R \oplus R \oplus R \oplus R$ can be written as $(R,R,R,R)$?

Thanks for the help

Comment: I suppose you need to chase down what you mean by $\oplus$.

Comment: All you've given is a map in one direction. You need to write down an inverse map and show it's a homeomorphism. This is an almost vacuous problem, so it might feel like you're not doing anything, but you do need to do a bit more than this.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Apologies,I'm using it for external Direct product. So symbolically $G_1 \oplus G_2 \oplus ... \oplus G_n = (g_1,g_2,...,g_n)$ where $g_i \in G_i$

Comment: Yep, so, as Kevin Carlson pointed out you merely need to show the map is invertible. Since your map is clearly linear is suffices to show the kernel is trivial. Although, the inverse map is also trivial to write down. I see GenericNickname has also hit these points in his answer. In short, you're correct, just flesh out the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic you need to show that there exists an isomorphism $\phi : M \to N$. $\phi$ has to be bijective (injective & surjective) and linear, i.e. you have to show

1. $\phi$ is linear: $\phi(A + B) = \phi(A) + \phi(B)$ for all $A,B \in M$.
2. $\phi$ is injective: Since $\phi$ is linear, this is equivalent to $\ker \phi = \left\lbrace A \in M : \phi(A) = 0 \right\rbrace = \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace$.
3. $\phi$ is surjective: For every $v \in N$ there exists an $A \in M$ such that $\phi(A) = v$.

Alternatively, you may just show that both are real vector spaces with dimension $4$.

Another hint: Yes, $R \oplus R \oplus R \oplus R = \left\lbrace (r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4) : r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4 \in R \right\rbrace$. At least that's what '$\oplus$' meant in my algebra courses (the direct sum of vector spaces).

Comment: Sorry, but is it possible to explain the alternative option? I'm not sure I follow. I guess even with all of that I'm still a bit lost

Comment: @bobbybreast The alternative solution would require you to utilize a result from a lecture/book: If $V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces over the same field $K$, then they are isomorphic if and only if $\dim_K V = \dim_K W$. However, this is an abstract statement and I think you would be better off using the first solution :)

Comment: Hmmm, thats beyond my current scope I believe. The last thing I'm struggling with is how to actually prove that $\phi$ is linear. I see what I have to do, but I'm not sure how to do that with $(a,b,c,d)$

Comment: @bobbybreast You already stated that you want to map $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$ to $(a,b,c,d)$. Then just put in the sum of two matrices and see what happens from there on. You can also use that $(a,b,c,d) + (a',b',c',d') = (a+a', b+b', c+c', d+d')$ since you are using the external direct product.

Comment: @bobbybreast Also I just realized that you are just talking about groups and not vector spaces. Then you only have to show $\phi(A) + \phi(B) = \phi(A+B)$ in order to show that $\phi$ is linear (fixed it in my answer as well).

Comment: Is the fact that $R \oplus R \oplus R \oplus R$ can be written as $(R,R,R,R)$ needed for the proof? I believe I got the proof without it. I simply proved the Map was linear, and bijective.

Comment: @bobbybreast I'd say you need that to show the map's linearity.